# How to control file uploads in a SharePoint Picture Library?

Tags: sharepoint

How can I restrict file upload type and size for a WSS 3.0 Picture Library?

I know I can restrict file upload size for an entire SharePoint web application via Central Admin / Application Management / Web Application General Settings. I can also block file types for the web application on the Central Admin / Operations / Blocked File Types pages. But those settings are for the entire application. I want want to only allow up to 1MB image file types in my Picture Library, but allow larger document in other libraries. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create an SPItemEventReceiver feature that uses the ItemAdding event to cancel the upload if it is larger then 1 MB.  You will have to cast the ListItem to a document to get the size if I recall correctly.  Use the EventReciever manager from codeplex http://speventhandlermanage.codeplex.com/ to hook your event handler up to the right list or use a feature to attach it all lists that have the Image content type.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that

This Project has no releases.

This is writing on download page.

May be it is possible to create event handler with other tools?